# How can I change a global variable that have the same name as a local variable in Rebol or Red?

Tags: rebol, red

I cannot change the value of global variable a within f because it has the same name as a local variable: when function returns, a is still 1 instead of 12.

```
a: 1
f: func[a][set 'a a]
>> f 12
== 12
>> a
== 1
```

How can I refer to global variable a ? Isn't set supposed to only refer to global variable ? Am I obliged to change my local variable name to do so or is there a way to keep both name ?

Comment: *"Isn't set supposed to only refer to global variable"*  What you might be thinking of is the difference between using a SET-WORD! in a FUNCTION body--which is gathered to suggest you want a local automatically--vs. avoiding the use of any SET-WORD!s in a FUNCTION body at all and doing an assignment via SET of a LIT-WORD!, in which case the binding that the LIT-WORD! you are assigning had in the body code prior to FUNCTION will be used for the assignment.  *(Yes, this is kind of Rube-Goldberg-inspired.  :-P)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `system/words/` path prefix to force read or write access to a word in global context:

```
>> a: 1
>> f: func[a][system/words/a: a]
== func [a][system/words/a: a]
>> f 12
== 12
>> a
== 12
```